What animated film featured people fighting a giant robotic worm?
I recall seeing an animated film from Japan or Korea featuring a giant worm-like robot.

The robot resembled the sand creature from Dune, but was made from metal.
The robot would try to find metal things and these parts would become part of itself.
People lived in a place safe from the robot's attacks, but in poverty. The robot seemed to have them surrounded.
The robot's territory was a wasteland of trash.
The main characters drove off-road vehicles and tried to outrun the robot.
The animation style was probably similar to the of the Korean film Wonderful Days or American Titan A.E.. It used some CGI.
I saw the film in ~2005.


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Vexille is probably what you're thinking of, I was looking for it too and found it shortly after seeing post. 

Some of the nanotech went amok, creating the "Jags", giant whirling constructs of semisentient metal that prowl the wilderness. The Jags destroyed all of Japan, save Tokyo which is protected by an inedible wall of ceramic.

